# toggle link with show hide using jQuery cookie

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
<p class="adv-toggle-buttons">             
     <a id="button_open" href="#" style="display: none;">[+] Open advanced unit options</a>
     <a id="button_close" href="#">[-] Close advanced unit options</a>
   </p>
```

and

```
 <div class="adv-unit-options">div elements here to be hidden/toggled</div>
```

script

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button_open').hide(); //initially we keep the open button hidden

 $('#button_close').click(function () {
  $(this).hide(); //this hides the close button as the div is now closed
  $('.adv-unit-options').slideUp('fast'); //hides the div
  $('#button_open').show(); //shows the open button
  $.cookie("openclose","closed", {expires: 1}); // sets cookie
  return false;
});

$("#button_open").click(function () {
  $(this).hide(); //hides the open button as the div is now open
  $('.adv-unit-options').slideDown('fast'); //shows the div
  $('#button_close').show(); //shows the close button
  $.cookie("openclose","open", {expires: 1}); //sets cookie
  return false;
});

 if($.cookie("openclose") == "closed") {
    $("#button_close").hide();
    $("#button_open").show();
    $('.adv-unit-options').hide();
    };
});
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to have this in reverse - Initially I want to  have [+] Open advanced unit options (this to be visible) and the div with the class of 'adv-unit-options' to be hidden.

The page I'm working on has a submit button so on page refresh/reload I want to remember what was last selected

Any help would be much appreciated
regards NickP

Comment: Your comments also say: "Initially, we keep the open button hidden", so the close button is present together with a visible .adv-unit-options div. Your questions tates: "Initially I want to have [+] Open advanced unit options and the div with the class adv-unit-options hidden". Both hidden? The open option visible and the div hidden? Please review your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Yoeri - do you have an alternative? i.e not cookie-based? Bear in mind I'm fairly new to jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yoeri/dVFaV/)

EDIT: Cookie code and link to JQuery cookie added to keep visibility state.

Y.

Comment: That's is great Thanks Yeori but I know how to do that - I have to appologise as I didn't make my question clear. The page I'm working on has a form so on submit/page reloads I want to remember what was selected. I should edit my question I've just been frustrated :-(

Comment: you can keep the cookie solution, don't see any problem with that (except expiration in one day).

Comment: do you know how to do it in reverse? i.e have  [+] Open advanced unit options (visible first) and the div with the class adv-unit-options hidden by default? like so: http://jsfiddle.net/dVFaV/20/

Comment: But if I expand - page reloads goes back to default settings - hence need the $.cookie plugin as above

Comment: Yoeri - I answered my own question, finally worked it out. Thanks for your time today

Answer (score 0):

hey yoeri I think I may have worked this out finally...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$(".adv-unit-options").hide();
   $('a.btn-trigger').text('[+] open advance unit options');

   // if cookie exist:
  if ($.cookie('openclose') == 'open') {
    $('.adv-unit-options').show();
    $('.adv-toggle-btn').addClass('expanded');
    $('a.btn-trigger').text('[-] close advance unit options');
}

  $(".adv-toggle-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded'); // toggle class
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) { 
        $.cookie('openclose', 'open', {expires: 1} ); //create cookie if .expanded is added to button
        $('a.btn-trigger').text('[-] close advance unit options');
    }
    else {
        $.cookie('openclose', null, {expires: 1} ); // else: delete cookie
        $('a.btn-trigger').text('[+] open advance unit options');
    };
    $(this).next('.adv-unit-options').animate({
        height: 'toggle', 
        opacity: 'toggle'
        },400);
    return false
  }); 
});

   HTML
   <p class="adv-toggle-btn"><a href="#" class="btn-trigger"></a></p>
   <div class="adv-unit-options">div elements here to be hidden/toggled</div>
```